# With Whom was Isabelle Speaking At the End

Tags: plot-explanation, character, blood-orange

As "[Blood Orange](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4145108/)" (2016 version) draws to an ending, Isabelle makes two telephone calls:

1. From inside the villa, she presumably calls the police and reports
   that her husband has been murdered.  She speaks in Spanish. The
   telephone is a 1960's style rotary dial model (if that's of any use)
   and she leaves the phone off the hook when the conversation is ended
   (if that's of any use).
2. From outside the villa, next to the swimming pool. This time she
   uses a small mobile phone and makes the simple statement, "It's
   done" (in English).

*Who did she call*? All of the principal characters are dead. Or presumed dead. Did one of the principals fake their death and slip away off camera? The whole film dwelled upon Isabelle's devotion to Bill, so we should assume either she was faking her devotion to him and now speaking to her true lover? Or could it have been Bill's estate lawyer?  It's a great film up to about the final two minutes where this messy ending jumps in from left field and intervenes.

Also: is there significance in leaving the inside phone off the hook? Are we supposed to infer something from this?

Comment: it was a white cell phone, like lucas, was it his?... did she talk to his wife?, was she involved too?... could be another posibility, don´t you think?

Comment: I'd love to know the same. Great movie but a very confusing ending. Maybe the song at the end means something. Money kills love..... greed.